# Gapless looping in Background Media Player for Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

I'm creating an app (Windows Runtime) that requires sound to run in the background (even when the phone is locked) so I set the `BackgroundMediaPlayer's` `isLoopingEnabled` property to true in the background task but when I play back the audio in the app there is about a 1 second gap between the audio finishing and starting again.

I've also tried setting the `position` property of the player to 0 on the `MediaEnded` event but that bared the same result.

Is there any way to achieve gapless looping using the BackgroundMediaPlayer in Windows Phone 8.1???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no workaround for this feature AFAIK but Gapless Audio support is coming with upcoming Windows 10.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I guess I'll have to wait for the time being. Do you know if it's possible using Silverlight or targeting Windows phone 8?

Comment: Details are unclear , but it's minimum supported platform will be Windows Phone 8.1 (WinRT) IMO.